# Proxying existing api with AWS API Gateway

Tags: java, rest, api, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am pretty new to AWS API Gateway. Still exploring the platform. I have used it with lambda functions and everything works fine.

Now coming to the problem at hand, I have an existing set of APIs hosted on EC2 instances. My current requirement is to audit the APIs, set tokens for users, audit usage and charge accordingly.

What I got from reading the docs is that API gateway gives you such features out of the box. So what I want to know is can API Gateway be used as a proxy to my already existing backend API? If yes, can someone give me some references/guides which I can refer to during the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you may have already read these, but the AWS docs for [Build an API Gateway API with HTTP Integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-http-integrations.html) is the guide you want to follow. You can use the proxy or custom approach based on your needs.